# How to wrap each symbol inside tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a counter with dinamic number, to style it as I want I need to wrap each number in tag.

My code:

```
<div class="test">12345</div>
```

I need:

```
<div class="test"><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span></div>
```

Is it any easy solution with jQuery to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:

```
var characters = $("div").text().split("");

$("div").empty();

$.each(characters, function(i, el) {
   $("div").append("<span>"+el+"</span");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6mJh/1/

Comment: Apparently the `split` is unneeded there.  strings can be indexed like arrays as in Nico's answer.

Comment: Ah, I have a number 100584 for example but after applying script it shows next numbers 012345...

Comment: @Kuzzy without adding a delimiter to your numbers there will be no algorithmic method to pull a number out with more than one digit. There simply is no way to tell (even from a human standpoint) if you handed me the number 101, this could be (1, 0, 1)  or (10, 1) or (1, 01) or (101)

Comment: @Matthew Cox thanks for your answer, but I do not need to wrap more then one digit. I get a number from DB and just want to separate it for single digits after page load to make it looks like indicator. Is it impossible to save a digits order?

Comment: I mean it always should be (1, 0, 1) but not (10, 1) or (1, 01) or (101).

Comment: @Kuzzy Ok just wanted to stress the point, sounded like an earlier comment was leading to that direction. As to your ordering issue, if\ they are digits coming froming a database. Then you could just add an ORDER BY clause to your SQL query to place them in order before they are put into the div

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = $(".test").html();
var result = "";

for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  result += "<" + "span>" + s[i] + "</" + "span>";
}

$(".test").html(result);
```

I separated the `<span>` tags because I'm not sure javascript allows them...

Comment: This won't handle any double or greater number of digits probably ... example: the number 10 would look like <span>1</span><span>0</span>

Comment: You can have `<` and `>` in strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $('.text').text();
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
{
   $('.text').append('<span>' + text[i] + '</span>);
}
```

This will only work for number 0-9. You won't be able to handle double digits or greater if you have them side by side with no delimiters like that. Not sure if there was a potential for  such a case.

Answer (score 0):

James Montagne's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6428040/1250044) but a bit nicer.

```
var chars = $("div").text().split("");
$("div").empty();
$.each(chars, function (i, el) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = chars[i];
    $("div").append(span);
});
```